# Where do you get the sqlj libaries for java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, db2, sqlj

I've been charged with writing a DB manipulator with java for a project.
My professor gives us material that says to use the sqlj library (Oracle I'm assuming?), but nobody explains where it comes from or how do download it.
I've been looking for hours now.

Answer (score 2):

The SQLJ site?

http://www.sqlj.org/

Unless you mean the executable, but I'm not sure what that is:

http://www.oracleutilities.com/OSUtil/sqlj.html

Answer (score 2):

The jars you're looking for are in Oracle Database Client. You can download it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Answer (score 1):

SQLJ is not a library, it is a language extension - this means you'll have to use a preprocessor to compile your java code to .sqlj files, which can then be executed. It's not as simple as including a library.

[this](http://onjava.com/onjava/2001/12/05/learning_sqlj.html) might get you started - you will need an Oracle environment on your machine though, I'm not sure if it's freely available

Answer (score 0):

You can download DB2 Express-C and compile your SQLj classes, generate the java files, and access plans for the database.

Answer (score -1):

Usually when you look for libraries, try typing: *library-name maven repository*, that will usually give you the right library, if not - that means "The library is kinda unusable and there are lots of better tools".

P.S.: Don't listen to your professor, just do it using standard JDBC or JPA.

Comment: Do you think it is wise to ignore the given requirements of the client (in this case the professor) if you don't like them?

Comment: @ChristianUhl, [Your Customers Do not Mean What They Say](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Your_Customers_Do_not_Mean_What_They_Say), usually.